# Are there any standard Java classes with inconsistent compareTo() and equals()?

Tags: java

I'm looking for all standard Java classes for which `compareTo()` can return `0` while `equals()` returns `false`:

```
Comparable comparable1 = ???;
Comparable comparable2 = ???;

assert comparable1.compareTo(comparable2) == 0;
assert !comparable1.equals(comparable2);
```

I know just one: `new BigDecimal("1.0")` is equal to `new BigDecimal("1")` using `compareTo()` but not equal using `equals()`. Are there any others?

I'm interested in all such classes, but only from public Java API. I need it to provide thorough documentation for AssertJ's [`UnevenComparableAssert`](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/assertj/core/api/UnevenComparableAssert.java) interface.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @ErikVesteraas, I've managed to reproduce additional example:

```
Calendar calendar1 = new GregorianCalendar(0, 0, 0);
Calendar calendar2 = new GregorianCalendar(0, 0, 0);
calendar2.setLenient(false);

Comparable comparable1 = calendar1;
Comparable comparable2 = calendar2;

assert comparable1.compareTo(comparable2) == 0; // compareTo compares along the timeline
assert !comparable1.equals(comparable2); // equals compares state, leniency is different
```

Comment: Good question, and as far as I know at least, `BigDecimal` is the only one in the JDK

Comment: As for the question you just deleted, what is the use-case here?  Do you need an exhaustive list?

Comment: I'm working on AsssertJ and trying to think of any other examples besides `BigDecimal` to document this class: https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/assertj/core/api/UnevenComparableAssert.java

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html Are you asking for classes that are known to implement comparible if so its listed above

Comment: Why does it not surprise me that both answers to date include something to do with time?!

Comment: This is a list question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There actually seems to be a few examples, but some are not well documented in the code or JavaDoc. [This blog post](http://blog.joda.org/2012/11/pitfalls-of-consistent-with-equals.html) by Stephen Colebourne gives the details, but in summary the following classes are inconsistent with equals:

- [java.math.BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)
- [java.io.ObjectStreamField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectStreamField.html)
- [javax.management.ObjectName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/ObjectName.html) (have not been able to reproduce an example though)
- [java.util.Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)
- [java.util.GregorianCalendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

For example:

```
ObjectStreamField a = new ObjectStreamField("foo", String.class);
ObjectStreamField b = new ObjectStreamField("foo", String.class);
a.equals(b); // false, checks object equality
a.compareTo(b); // 0
```

As noted by Olivier, Java 8 also adds [java.time.zone.ZoneOffsetTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneOffsetTransition.html)

Notably [java.time.OffsetTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html) has avoided inconsistency by adding extra methods `isAfter`, `isBefore` and `isEqual` for doing time-line comparison/equality-checking.

Answer (score 10):

Looking for "inconsistent with equals" in the JDK classes, I also found `java.time.zone.ZoneOffsetTransition`